# F# core .NET framework on Linux build how-to

Tags: f#, dotnet-cli, ionide

I'm trying to build a F# project (console) on Ubuntu 17.10 (Mono 4.6.2) however I run into F# core .NET issues. For reference, I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.21.2 and ionide extensions (new project and FAKE build). Below is the output.

I've tried adding an explicit reference to different versions of Fsharp.core e.g. 4.2, 4.3.4 with no luck.

Where should I be looking at to sort this out?

```
Finished Target: InstallDotNetCLI
Starting Target: Restore (==> InstallDotNetCLI)
/home/lear/.local/share/dotnetcore/dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for /home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj...
/home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'FSharp.Core (>= 4.3.4)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
  Restore failed in 99.61 ms for /home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj.
Running build failed.


 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="fsTest.fsproj">
      <Name>fsTest.fsproj</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="fsTest.fs" />
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="..\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets" />
</Project>
```

I used this instructions as reference for my setup:
*[Four easy steps for installing F# on Ubuntu Linux](https://medium.com/@edgarsanchezg/four-easy-steps-for-installing-f-in-ubuntu-linux-88122323f12b)* (2017-07-03)

Comment: It seems your project is targeting full .NET framework instead of .NET Core. Can you show the very top few lines of the project file?

Comment: To be fair I believe the ionide extensions deliberately intend to target the full framework via mono.  (fsharp core does not imply .net core)

Comment: You should try creating a new project. Or clean out the `obj` folder as well and remove the ItemGroup with `ProjectReference`. Do you need `mono`? If not you can quickly create a dotnet core project via the `dotnet new` CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project file specifies the wrong `TargetFramework`. Changing that to e.g. `netcoreapp2.0` [Target Framework Moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks) should fix the build.

Comment: Good point; However the build still fails
/
  
/home/lear/.local/share/dotnetcore/sdk/2.0.2/NuGet.targets(792,5): error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk". [/home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj]
  Restoring packages for /home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj...
/home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj : error NU1108: Cycle detected. 
/home/lear/src/fsTest/fsTest/fsTest.fsproj : error NU1108:   fsTest -> fsTest.

Comment: It's building now; only problem is that is a dll? and I want an exe file?? how do I do that or dot net core only geneates dll?

Comment: You can either run the dll with `dotnet YourProject.dll` or publish for a specific runtime, e.g. `dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.10-x64`, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: If you need more follow-up help, it might be worthwile to ask another SO question.

Answer (score 2):

The project you are trying to build/restore is referencing itself. Just remove this portion from the `fsproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="fsTest.fsproj">
      <Name>fsTest.fsproj</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```